# How to render a form through a plugin on a wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, custom-wordpress-pages

I am practicing the creation of a wordpress plugin and so far I have made progress by installing the plugin and displaying it in the administration bar of the administrator user through the following code.

```
if( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

/**
 * Print SEO tags in the header
 * 
 * @return void
 */

function opt_menu_cactaceas() {
    ?>

    <h1>Registrador de Cactaceas</h1>
    <p>En el siguiente formulario podra registrar diferentes cactaceas</p>
    <p> Formulario 1 </p>

    <?php

}

function agregar_a_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Pluging Cactaceas', 'Plug. Cactaceas', 'manage_options', 'plugin_cactaceas_link', 'opt_menu_cactaceas');

}

add_action("admin_menu", "agregar_a_menu");
```

**My current goal is to be able to do that when loading a page (for example mydomain.com/form - which is only one page and will not be associated with any article) the plugin renders a form which subsequently records information in a table of the bd Wordpress that I have already configured.**

Performing some tests I have managed to find the "the_content" hook filter which, through the following code, allows me to render HTML tags but only within the created articles but as I wish that HTML tags be rendered directly on a page, it does not come out nothing.

```
function wetuts_author_bio( $content ) {
    return $content . "<h1>hola diego</h1>";
}

add_filter('the_content', 'wetuts_author_bio');
```

**My question would be if they know of any hook or hook table where the associated ones to the rendering of a page show me since I have not been able to find any.**

the hook that I found "the_content" only comes into operation when an article is being rendered (upon entering the article) so it is not useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to create a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for the form in your custom plugin then you can use that shortcode directly in page editor.

You can create a shortcode like this:

```
function registration_form($atts){
    $html = '<h1>Hello</h1>';
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode("registrationform", "registration_form");
```

Then add a shortcode `[registrationform]` in any page editor

Please checkout this [tutorial](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-a-shortcode-in-wordpress/) for more detail.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25280268)

Comment: @TylerH should I improve the answer? what you are trying to say sorry didn't get it?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the review queue puts less-than-helpful auto comments on posts. Yes, you should edit the answer to include the gist of what the links discuss. That way, when the links go down, this answer doesn't lose its value. This is a policy on the site to prevent common issues with linkrot (and to prevent people spending unnecessary time jumping through site link after site link). Also FYI, I'm not the one who downvoted your post.

Comment: Hi @Asif, I'm not the downvoter, but I can say that, while in practical terms, the Shortcode API is a good tool for implementing HTML in filtered content areas - in this case it has a direct conflict with the question at hand, which is asking for help outputting arbirtary HTML on a url path that doesn't exist and doesn't fall within WordPress' default permalink structure, ie a "virtual page".

Comment: @Xhynk oh no he didn't mention this that i am rendering HTML on a page which doesn't exist. He is simply asking how can i render form on that specific page.

Comment: @Asif thank for te help. I use your tutorial and a couple more to understand the idea of shortcode achieving the desired.

Comment: Great, I am glad to help you out.